# Comparing value submitted by user to database, redirecting based on results

Tags: php, html, mysql, user-input

I am trying to build a webpage, that allows users to enter a code (numbers and letters only). Based on if the code is a "winner", it will redirect them to a "winner" page on my website. Otherwise, it will redirect them to a "losing" page. I'm new to this, but I'm trying to learn!

HTML:

```
<h1>Break Open Your Code</h1>
<form target="_blank" action="phpfile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="1" />
    <label>Enter Your Code Here</label> 
    <input type="text" name="answer" /> 
    <input onclick="window.location.href = 'results-page.html';" type="submit" value="Check your Code" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Connect to your MySQL database
$dbhst = "localhost";
$dbnme = "mydatabase"; 
$bdusr = "myusername";
$dbpws = "mypassword";

// Using PDO to connect

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhst.';dbname='.$dbnme, $bdusr, $dbpws);

// Getting variables
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
$questionID = $_POST['questionID'];

// Comparing answers

try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_with_answers WHERE question='" . $questionID . "' and answer='". $answer . "' LIMIT 0,1');
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if ( count($result) ) {
        foreach($result as $row) { 
            echo 'Congrats, you've entered a correct code';
            // Do Something Else
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Your code did not win. Please try again.';
        exit;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: You dont have a form field called `name="questionID"` so there will be no `$_POST['questionID']`

Comment: There are fields called `answer` and `code` however!

Comment: And unfortunately our script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: `$_POST['questionID']` should be `$_POST['code']`

Comment: The piece you are missing is redirecting to another script, for that you need `header('Location: winner.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `onclick="window.location.href = 'results-page.html';"`

and modify `<input type="hidden" name="code" value="1" />`

to `<input type="hidden" name="questionID" value="1" />`

HTML :

```
<h1>Break Open Your Code</h1>
<form target="_blank" action="phpfile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="questionID" value="1" />
    <label>Enter Your Code Here</label> 
    <input type="text" name="answer" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Check your Code" />
</form>
```

save html file to form.html

now modify phpfile.php

add `header("Location: winner.html");` if code is correct

add `header("Location: losing.html");` if code is incorrect

PHP :

```
<?php
// Connect to your MySQL database
$dbhst = "localhost";
$dbnme = "mydatabase"; 
$bdusr = "myusername";
$dbpws = "mypassword";

// Using PDO to connect

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhst.';dbname='.$dbnme, $bdusr, $dbpws);

// Getting variables
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
$questionID = $_POST['questionID'];

// Comparing answers

try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_with_answers WHERE question='" . $questionID . "' and answer='". $answer . "' LIMIT 0,1");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if ( count($result) ) {
        foreach($result as $row) { 
            // echo 'Congrats, you've entered a correct code';
            header("Location: winner.html");
        }
    } else {
        // echo 'Your code did not win. Please try again.';
        header("Location: losing.html");
        exit;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

create html winner.html and losing.html

winner.html : `Congrats, you've entered a correct code`

losing.html : `Your code did not win. Please try again.`

Comment: I'm getting an error on line 20 in the PHP code: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ')' "    Have any idea why that  might be?

Comment: updated my answer, fix single quote to double quote. ( ' ) to ( " )